# How can I find pdf of this dirichlet distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$Y=(Y_1,\dotsb,Y_k)^t \sim Dirichlet(a_1,...,a_k,a_{k+1})$ when all $a_i = 1(i=1,\dotsb,k+1)$

I used definition to find pdf of this dirichlet distribution.

> $f(y)={\Gamma(k+1) \over {\Gamma(1) \dotsb \Gamma(1)}} (\prod{^k_{i=1}} {y_i}^{1-1}) (1-y_1-\dotsb -y_k)^{1-1} I_{(y_1>0, \dotsb,y_k>0,y_1+\dotsb +y_k <1)}$
>
> $=k!I_{(y_1>0, \dotsb,y_k>0,y_1+\dotsb +y_k <1)}$

I'm not sure about this result. Is it right?

Comment: Looks fine (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Special_cases). This is just uniform distribution on $S=\{(y_1,\ldots,y_k):y_1,\ldots,y_k>0,\sum_{i=1}^k y_i<1\}$, in which case volume of $S$ is $1/k!$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank for your comment! It helped me to understand this problem!!